# Insert Missing Data in Slave Database

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave

We have a master slave replication [MySQL 5.6]. However In slave database 2 rows is missing in one table. I've tried to solve this using Percona Toolkit as suggested [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/14224/71925).

> But `pt-table-checksum` requires statement-based replication, and it sets `binlog_format=STATEMENT` on the master, but due to a MySQL limitation replicas do not honor this change. Therefore, checksums will not replicate past any replicas using row-based replication that are masters for further replicas.

***So what if:***

1. **Insert the rows directly into the slave database**

```
SET SQL_LOG_BIN=0;

INSERT INTO `tbl_name` (`id`, `column1`, ...)
VALUES ( 4321, 'some val', ...),
       ( 4344, 'some val2', ...);
```

2. **Run a `REPLACE INTO` query in Master database**

```
REPLACE INTO `tbl_name` (`id`, `column1`, ...)
VALUES ( 4321, 'some val', ...);

REPLACE INTO `tbl_name` (`id`, `column1`, ...)
VALUES ( 4344, 'some val2', ...);
```

Can someone suggest which method is safe and reliable. Is this the right way to solve the issue. Is there any risk of doing this?

Comment: My opinion on data differences between master and slave is that you can not know, if you detected all differences. Whenever there's a mismatch pull a fresh backup from master and rebuild replication. After that set the slave in read only mode!

Comment: Thanks @fancyPants. But what about the data written while taking the backup. I'm not allowed to take downtime. And data writing frequency is high.

Comment: Have a look at percona xtrabackup. No downtime required at all. https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/8.0/index.html But get familiar with this tool! No quick shots on live servers!

Comment: Percona XtraBackup 8.0 does not support making backups of databases created in versions prior to 8.0 of MySQL

Comment: Well, you can choose an earlier version.